# how to test Promoting Your In-App Purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase, xcode9-beta5

I am new in ios Development iOS11 Apple introduced IAP purchases that can be initiated from the AppStore & it can be displayed in search results, and may be featured on an appropriate tab on the App Store.

for me not showing where Can i see the promoting my In-App Purchases UI ?

**Testing Promoted In-App Purchases**

To test your promoted in-app purchases before your app is available in the App Store, Apple provides a system URL that triggers your app using the itms-services:// protocol.

**The resulting URL looks like this:**

itms-services://?action=purchaseIntent&bundleId=com.example.app&productIdentifier=product_name

Answer (score 5):

You can set up your in-app promotions at iTunesConnect under related **app's page -> features -> App Store Promotions**

Your in-app purchases won't actually show up in the App Store, until you've submitted a binary that has appropriate delegate methods.

You can use that URL for testing before go live. Once you have constructed this URL has the ITMS services protocol and three parameters.

**The resulting URL looks like this:** itms-services://?action=purchaseIntent&bundleId=com.example.app&productIdentifier=product_name

You can simple send this URL to yourself in an email or iMessage and open it from your device and tap it, your app will be opened automatically. So you will know the test is running when your app opens automatically. And you can then test your promoted in-app purchase's behavior from there.

**You can find more information at** [Add an in-app purchase to promote (iOS)](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deve3105860f)

Comment: can i test Promoting In-App purchases in simulator?

Comment: @YogendraPatel you can't test this on the simulator as there is no App Store app installed.

Comment: Just want to add that it is also not possible to test this link with a release version of the app. Just works on debug version.

Comment: @vauxhall Interesting. The documentation says nothing about debug vs. release. How would one go about doing this? Upload a `Debug` build to TestFlight, download to device, then tap the system URL? Is that how this should work? Thanks!

Comment: @West1 I don't think you can test this on TestFlight, at least not before the Promotion is live. Also I don't think you can send a debug build to TestFlight either. To test it you can only do it on Ad-Hoc (Running the app via Xcode or installing it directly).